# my elastic beanstalk application doesn't reflect the latest commit in the live environment

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am deploying my Django app via the eb CLI. I commit my changes to git and deploy (with eb deploy). In the past I would see my changes reflected after a deploy, now I do not. It is as if the application version is being cached on EB's side.Thanks in advance for any help.

I checked the source on S3 and it is the latest version, so I have no idea why the live site (also accessed via eb open after deployment to be sure) doesn't reflect. I added some simple console logging to be certain, and it is missing. I've tried restarting the server and rebuilding the environment. Nothing has worked. I also deleted all previous application versions, so the only remaining one has the changes I want, then redeployed and restarted. Still not the version I want running on the environment.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my issue. I have a Django + React app, and the main.js file from the frontend react component was not updating. I was committing the un-updated main.js file. I managed to update it by running 'npm run dev' from the frontend directory. I'll look to automate this going forward - yet to be worked out. –